# CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using `Entity Framework 7` Code First

I have a function that needs to returns a list of Countries(ids,Names) linked to a User.
The User isn't directly linked to the Country but is linked via the City. City is linked to State. State is linked to Country.

I decided to use a GroupBy to get the list of countries.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
 {
  var table = await _db.Cities
      .Include(ci => ci.States.Country)
      .Select(ci => ci.States.Country)
      .OrderBy(co => co.CountryName)
      .GroupBy(co=>co.pk_CountryId)
      .ToListAsync()
      ;
      return table;

 }
```

However I get the error:

> CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List  <System.Linq.IGrouping>` to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List`'

1. How do I return a variable `IEnumerable<Country>` as that is what the receiving code expects i.e. a list of Countries?
2. Am I doing my grouping correct?
3. For performance I assume grouping is better than a distinct or a contains

Comment: Remove the grouping...

Comment: I can use distinct but always thought grouping is better for performance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the distinct countries, you can use a select afterwards to select the first country in each `IGrouping<int,Country>`:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
 {
 return await _db.Cities
  .Include(ci => ci.States.Country)
  .Select(ci => ci.States.Country)
  .OrderBy(co => co.CountryName)
  .GroupBy(co=>co.pk_CountryId)
  .Select(co => co.FirstOrDefault())
  .ToListAsync();
 }
```

Also a little sidenote, the `Include` isn't necessary here, eager loading the countries would only be useful if you were to return the `States` and wanted its `Country` property be populated. The `Select` makes sure you're grabbing the `Country`, you're not even fetching the states anymore from database.

Comment: You did write `FirstOrDefault()` and not just `FirstOrDefault` right? If the "co" in the select is an `IGrouping<int,Country>` that should compile. `FirstOrDefault()` is a method not a property.

Comment: Missed the brackets. However I now get runtime error `InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element`

Comment: @devc2 that is probably an error caused by a `Single` or `SingleOrDefault()` in your code and not related to this code block.

Comment: I'm only using FirstOrDefault()